# DAX to multiply two max date measures

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, multiplication

I am fairly new to Power BI and was hoping to solve my total (multiplication problem).

I have running inventory table for supplies ordered. I need to have a breakdown of the cost of those supplies based on the last item ordered(prices constantly change). I have two measures, one for the latest cost, and the second for the latest units used.

```
Latest Unit/Cost = 
VAR maxdate = MAX(InventoryJ[Date Ordered])

RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(InventoryJ[Cost/Unit]),
InventoryJ[Date Ordered]=maxdate)
```

and

```
Latest UnitsUsed = 
VAR maxdate = MAX(InventoryJ[Date Ordered])

RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(InventoryJ[Unit Used]),
InventoryJ[Date Ordered]=maxdate)
```

In my matrix they work great, even though the total is incorrect in the table.

[image]

Now I am stuck on multiplying these two measures together for the latest units used and the latest cost per unit.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
Latest Total Cost = [Latest Unit/Cost] * [Latest UnitsUsed]
```

Consider using this kind of test to fix your total row.

```
If ( HasOneValue ( InventoryType[Summary]), ...
```

Then put whatever high level aggreation you want into the FALSE condition of that IF statement.

Comment: I appreciate the response and  had tried the measure. However, it returns the total cost for only one of the supplies and not all of them.